# Can I trigger events off of outbound HTTP requests from an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Imagine an old app. Let's say, hypothetically, that it is 9 or 10 years old, it has enormous amounts of tech debt. It makes thousands of API calls to 3rd party APIs, and stores some of the data in the database. The code is brittle, and full of bugs. We are afraid to touch it, because it is so old and badly written. If we wanted to start logging every outbound API call, we could re-write the code, but that would take a year or two. I'm trying to get the job done in a day or two. I'm wondering, is there a way to route the outbound request, through some AWS service, such that I can trigger some event for each outbound request? If I could route every outbound request through some proxy, then the proxy could record every outbound request, and I wouldn't have to touch the code. But how exactly could I arrange to put such a proxy between the EC2 instance and the outside world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [AWS Traffic Mirroring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/what-is-traffic-mirroring.html). All traffic is sent to an instance to be logged or inspected. More detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-how-it-works.html).

Alternately you could put the app on an instance in a private subnet, set up a custom NAT instance in a public subnet that logs all traffic such as a squid proxy. [This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-an-outbound-vpc-proxy-with-domain-whitelisting-and-content-filtering/) will help you set squid up, then you'll need to configure logging. There's a premade version on the AWS Marketplace but you'll pay $0.05/hr for it.

Comment: Your last idea is what I want to do. Can you offer more information about Squid Proxy?

Comment: Sure, I've put a link in to a blog post that should help.